# Never show the term name if the user has no permission to view the term

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

I use a vocabulary to freetag bookmarks I post to my site, and I want to hide all the terms (also most nodes; most or all, I don't care).

With TAC module I use following setting for a start:

```
global default: Show/Create/Delete: ignore   Show-term-checkbox: yes
myvoc default:  Show(node) : disallow;       Show-term-checkbox: no
```

I have also tried with:

```
global default: Show/Create/Delete: ignore   Show-term-checkbox: no
```

I just want to make Drupal show the "access denied" or similar page on /taxonomy/term/xxx. I know my site doesn't show a link with that URL, but I just want to be sure.

Is it possible? Or should I use a simpler module?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what end result you'd like to achieve here? If we have an understanding of the intent, we might be able to suggest an alternative approach, if one is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [hook_menu_link_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/6) in a custom module and modify access to /taxonomy/term/xxx, if need be, by overriding the existing access callback with your own.

You will need to look at the menu router table to see exactly what menu item you want to alter.

Answer (score 0):

[Path Access](http://drupal.org/project/path_access) offers a simple way to display a 403 on any taxonomy/term/* page.